# Google API python credentials OAUTH server-server

Tags: python, json, oauth, aws-lambda, google-api-python-client

In my project i have developed a python script for check and create automatically an appointment on my google calendar.
First i create from google dev console OAUTH json file and then authenticate and run my script:

```py
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_id.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Calendar API Python Quickstart'


def get_credentials():

    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'calendar-python-quickstart.json')

    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

credentials = get_credentials()
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)
```

when i run it from my local machine all done, but when i upload the scripts and all dependencies using an AWS lambda function when i test it the server responde:

> {
>     "errorMessage": "module initialization error"
>   }
>
> START RequestId: 2244eefe-e3dd-11e7-a0ce-93ed40a4fa13 Version: $LATEST
>   module initialization error: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1060'

I think this is because the authentication method store and retrive the json credential file on local machine, but how can i authenticate and run code from server-server instead client-server?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the credentials part of your code, change it to get the default credentials from the machine, like this:

```
#import GoogleCredentials
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
```

On your lambda configuration set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as environment variable key and your credentials json file name as value.

It works on all my lambdas that use google api.